# getenv() returns different values in different programs for the same environment variable

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, ros, getenv

I am using ubuntu 14.04. I added the following code at the top of main() in a program, but I don't get anything printed when I run it.

```
char const* masteruri = getenv("ROS_MASTER_URI");
if (masteruri!=NULL){
printf ("The current masteruri is: %s",masteruri);
}
char const* rosdis = getenv("ROS_DISTRO");
if (rosdis!=NULL){
printf ("\n The current rosdis is: %s",rosdis);
}
```

but the same code in another program gives the expected result

```
 The current masteruri is: http://localhost:11311
 The current rosdis is: indigo
```

I have included stdlib.h and I exported the variables in etc/profile.d

Comment: _in a program_, _in another program_ **what** programs?

Comment: Also, how do you run these programs, the context is very important.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but printf was not working for some reason, I tried DEVLOG_INFO and noticed that variables values that were exported in /etc/profile.d could be returned with getenv() by both programs.